# Calling delete[] on array of objects corrupts heap for no reason

Tags: c++, delete-operator, heap-corruption

```
void Files::Push(const File& f)
{
    if(!s_)
    {
        files_ = new File[++s_];
        files_[0] = f;
        return;
    }

    File* tmp = new File[++s_];
    memcpy(tmp, files_, (s_-1) * sizeof(File));
    tmp[s_-1] = f;

    delete[] files_;

    files_ = tmp;
}
```

[Full code is kind of big.](https://github.com/ScienceDiscoverer/hello-world/blob/master/FileSysScanner.cpp) But for this particular problem, its really simple code, really simple classes. I really don't see what could went wrong in here. I don't call `delete[]` twice, I don't call `delete` instead of `delete[]`, I call it on same pointer that saved result of `new[]`. I thought, maybe some other code corrupts heap before this particular `delete[]`, but I double checked my custom string class (only one that deals with raw pointers) and it works 100% correctly.

In full code you can see some debug outputs. It crashes after trying to scan 3rd file or 4th file in folder, randomly...

```
D:\Dropbox\My Programs\FileSysScanner>fss
D:\Dropbox\My Programs\FileSysScanner\fss.exe
D:\Dropbox\My Programs\FileSysScanner\fss.exe Size: 45
D:\Dropbox\My Programs\FileSysScanner
fss.exe
Scanning...: D:\Dropbox\My Programs\FileSysScanner\*
File Found: fss.exe
1
2
Inside new pointer if... s: 0
3
4
Scanning...: fss.exe\*
FindFirstFileW() Failed! Error# 267
5
File Found: fss_first_prot.exe
1
2
push_1... s: 1
push_2... s: 2
push_3... s: 2
push_4... s: 2
push_5... s: 2
3
4
Scanning...: fss_first_prot.exe\*
FindFirstFileW() Failed! Error# 267
5
File Found: Main.cpp
1
2
push_1... s: 2
push_2... s: 3
push_3... s: 3
push_4... s: 3
<CRASH HERE>
```

File class depicted below. Now I'm thinking mb including Files in File was not the best idea... Maybe this is the problem...

```
class File
{
public:
    File();
    File(const wchar_t* n, ulong b, bool isf, bool hid, bool sys);

    const Fname& Name() const;
    ulong Bytes() const;
    void AddBytes(ulong b);
    bool IsFolder() const;
    bool IsHidden() const;
    bool IsSystem() const;

    void PushFile(const wchar_t* n, ulong b, bool isf, bool hid, bool sys);
    void PushFile(const File& f);

private:
    void SetBytes(ulong b);
    ulong BytesTaken(ulong b) const;
    // Data
    Fname fn_;
    Files fs_;
    // Folder, Hidden and System attributes stored here in upper bits
    ulong bytes_;
    ulong bytes_taken_;
};
```

**Edit:**

I fixed it with making proper deep copy constructor and assignment for Files and also for File too.

```
Files::Files(const Files& other) : s_(other.s_)
{
    files_ = new File[s_];
    for(int i = 0; i < s_; ++i)
    {
        files_[i] = other.files_[i];
    }
}

Files& Files::operator=(const Files& other)
{
    if(this != &other)
    {
        File* tmp = files_;
        if(other.s_ != s_)
        {
            s_ = other.s_;
            tmp = new File[s_];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < s_; ++i)
        {
            tmp[i] = other.files_[i];
        }

        delete[] files_;
        files_ = tmp;
    }

    return *this;
}
```

And also using simple loop instead of `memcopy` in `PushFile()`:

```
void Files::Push(const File& f)
{
    if(!s_)
    {
        files_ = new File[++s_];
        files_[0] = f;
        return;
    }
    File* tmp = new File[++s_];

    for(int i = 0; i < s_-1; ++i)
    {
        tmp[i] = files_[i];
    }

    tmp[s_-1] = f;

    delete[] files_;
    files_ = tmp;
}
```

Now, using Files in File is not a problem at all. Same as using raw pointers (if you know what are you doing, ofcourse). If I didn't try to oversimplify thing with this stupid memcopy usage on non-POD classes, all would be fine...

Thanks for help!

Comment: What's the definition of `File`? Please make your code a [mcve].

Comment: ... and why allocate a new `File` array for every push? Why not use a `std::vector<File>` that will handle that more effectively for you?

Comment: std::vector is simple. std::string is simple. It is hard to use them incorrectly. Pointers, new, delete, memcpy are NOT simple. It is very easy to use them incorrectly. You are successfully doing just that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo because I wanted to create my own solution and not rely on something made by others, even if its quicker.

Comment: So if you want to install new shelves at your house you grab an axe, go to the woods, chop and process a tree? Or do you go to the local home improvement store and buy ready made wood? Same thing with `std::vector` here.

Comment: @n.m. In the context of pointers new and deletes It is simple. Yes, I know, that STL has super simple solutions, but I'm not one of the people that can just use black box and be happy with it. I used pointers because I want to learn to use it perfectly. If you never use pointers, you never learn how to use it effectively.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, 1st rout would be the best for me. I would use second solution only if I would have no other choice. BTW I want to create my own integrated circuits sometime. MB simple CPUs too.

Comment: You have made more than one grave error in this supposedly simple context. If I were you, I would be very careful in expressing opinions about what is simple and what is not.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer I've been programming in C++ for more than 20 years and I would never waste time trying to get code like this to try to appear to work correctly given that it can never be made reliable. You're much better off learning how to do things right than learning the useless skill of making what appears to be a suspension bridge (but might collapse) with a teaspoon.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz At least it will truly be my own bridge, even if flimsy. And not something assembled of ready to use blocks.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer I will share one of the biggest things I wish I knew when I was younger -- never learn the wrong way to do something first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my custom string class (only one that deals with raw pointers)

Your `Files` class has a raw pointer so that's bugged. Your `File` class includes a `Files` object so that's wrong as well.

`memcpy` on non-POD types (such as `File`) is another bug.

Don't use raw pointers, or if you insist then make sure your classes have correct copying semantics. Don't memcpy objects, use copy constructors and assignment. The easy and efficient way to write your code would be to use `std::wstring` and `std::vector`.

Comment: vectors and strings use raw pointers too inside of em. And its not bugged.

Comment: Yea, with File including Files I agree, that seems wrong somehow... Oh yea and POD too... Facepalm...

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer Concerning pointers inside vectors and strings, you are right of course. But with those classes the hard work has been done so why not use it?

Answer (score 3):

There is just too much use of inappropriate low-level functions in high-level contexts to get this code to ever be reliable. This is the biggest problem I see:

```
memcpy(tmp, files_, (s_-1) * sizeof(File));
```

You can't use `memcpy` this way. For one thing, your `File` class has a `Files` element in it. Your `Files` class has a `File*` in it. When you do a `memcpy` on a `File`, its address changes, breaking all the places you've stashed raw pointers to it.

Wherever possible, use values instead of pointers. Values are easy to store and copy, don't have to be deleted, and can't dangle. Gratuitous use of raw pointers loses all of these benefits.

Comment: I don't see why people hate pointers so much. I use it, because if I can master it, it's very powerful tool. Yes it was indeed this memcopy fail. I wanted to oversimplify and make everything fast, and look what I got into... But well, at least I can learn on this mistake and hopefully avoid it in the future...

Answer (score 2):

Please note two things:

- `delete[]` calls destructors for all array elements being deleted;
- `memcpy` just copies bytes, without taking care of stuff that needs to be copied using copy constructors.

If your `File` class has something other than primitive types, e.g. pointers, you're in trouble, because when you `memcpy`, you don't copy those members properly. When you `delete[]` the original array, destructors are called for members of the deleted elements, which leave your `tmp` copy with invalid values.

It's better not to use `memcpy` for anything other than primitive types (e.g. integers). Use `std::vector` for storing your `File` objects, and use `push_back` to add new items to the vector.